# which one is correct "The Home Ministry" or "Home Ministry"?

Tags: articles, definite-article

I need some suggestion about the article in both these statement which one is grammatically correct? "The Home Ministry" or "Home Ministry"?

I was in college when my teacher teach me about articles. Its use with big or department whether that was right or wrong.

Comment: Whether to use the definite article with proper names is quite a complicated topic, but when speaking of a government department you would use _the_ (because it is the only organisation of that name in your country).

Comment: We would need some more context to answer this question. Can you use "home ministry" in a sentence?